# AWK doesn't work in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following AWK statement in a script:

```
grep -E $city $DATFILE | awk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= $minbed) && ($4 >= $minsqft) && ($5 <= $maxprice) && ($6 <= $maxweeks)' $DATFILE | sort -nk5 | less
```

When I run the script, the output is blank.  However, if I run the following:

```
grep -E Toronto listing.dat | awk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= 2) && ($4 >= 500) && ($5 <= 900000) && ($6 <= 10)' listing.dat | sort -nk4 | less
```

It outputs as expected.

I have no idea why this is happening, and I have even replaced the awk statement in the script to echo out the variables to make sure they're passing correctly and they are.

Here is the script thus far:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    DATFILE=listing.dat

    if [ -f ${DATFILE} ];
    then

            echo -n "Are you looking into anywhere in the GTA, or a specific city?: "
            read uinput

            if [ $uinput == "anywhere" ];
            then
                    echo "You have chosen anywhere"
            elif [ $uinput == "specific" ];
            then
                    echo -n "Which city?: "
                    read city

                    echo -n "Minimum Number of Bedrooms: "
                    read minbed

                    echo -n "Minimum Square Footage (500, 600, etc): "
                    read minsqft

                    echo -n "Maximum Price: "
                    read maxprice

                    echo -n "Maximum Weeks On Market: "
                    read maxweeks

                    echo -n "Sort by (price, sqrft, weeks): "
                    read sortby

                    if [ $sortby == "price" ];
                    then
                            echo -n "Sort by (asc, desc): "
                            read ascdesc
                            if [ $ascdesc == "asc" ];
                            then
                                    grep -E $city $DATFILE | awk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= $minbed) && ($4 >= $minsqft) && ($5 <= $maxprice) && ($6 <= $maxweeks)' $DATFILE | sort -nk5 | less
                        elif [ $ascdesc == "desc" ];
                        then
                                grep -E $city $DATFILE | awk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= $minbed) && ($4 >= $minsqft) && ($5 <= $maxprice) && ($6 <= $maxweeks)' $DATFILE | sort -rnk5 | less
                        fi
                fi

        fi

else
        echo "${DATFILE} Not found!"
fi
```

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: `gawk` or `awk`? You have both in your examples.

Comment: Your awk script is in single quotes.  Shell variables aren't expanded when they are inside signle quotes.  So you need to use -v to assign them to an awk variable.

Comment: In any case, don't pipe grep results to awk. awk is itself able to filter by regex

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  Can you give me an example of this, please?

Comment: @hek2mgl  I'm new to awk so I'm not sure how :(

Comment: @miken32 is there a difference?  I think ultimately I need gawk

Comment: "listing.dat" or "listings.dat"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams listing.dat -- I did that line by memory for the purpose of SO.  Sorry for the inaccuracy.

Comment: Because shell variables aren't expanded inside single quotes so `x=asd; y=qwe; echo | awk '{ print $x $y; }'` won't work.  But you can pass in variables like this: `x=asd; y=qwe; echo | awk -v y=$y -v x=$x '{ print x y; }'`

Comment: @DaveMelia Short lession: `egrep 'foo'` is the same as `awk '/foo/'`. If you want to add more logic, let's say you are only interested in line numbers greater than 10 containing that pattern use `awk 'NR>10 && /foo/'`.. And so on.. I've used `egrep` because awk is using extended POSIX regexes. It doesn't matter if the pattern is *foo*, but anyway, worth to mention it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Everything now works great -- however I'm unable to sort  with -nk4 -- the values remain unsorted.  Any idea why?

Comment: You set the delimiter for awk to `"[\t]+"` which would match more than one tab.  But sort uses any whitespace so you mayneed to set the field separator for sort using -t to the same value you use for awk.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Didn't seem to work using sort -t $'\t' -nk5 -- any ideas?

Comment: That's what I was trying to say.  `[\t]+`matches one or more tabs so if there is more than one tab between fields sort will get confused.  Are you sure there are multiple tabs between columns?  Maybe you should change the field separator for awk to be a single tab and see what hapens then.  If you don't need multiple tabs betweeb fields you could consolidate the tabs with `grep ... | sed -e 's/\t\t*/\t/g' | awk ... | sort ...` because then there would be just a single tab between fields.

Comment: Maybe upload the input file to pastebin or something so we can try it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah http://pastebin.com/6c4shh8L Is the code and http://pastebin.com/BjLseZVe is the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If new to any *nix utility, you can see basic docs using 'man utility_name'; from the man page for 'awk' (man awk):

> -v var=val
>         Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such variable values are available to the BEGIN block
>   of an AWK program.

There are other ways to do this, but following the docs your code would be changed to something like:

```
awk -F "[\t]+" \  
  -v MINBED=$minbed -v MINSQFT=$minsqft -v MAXPRICE=$maxprice -v MAXWEEKS=$maxweeks \
  '($3 >= MINBED) && ($4 >= MINSQFT) && ($5 <= MAXPRICE) && ($6 <= MAXWEEKS)'
```

Comment: Okay this is great.  It works perfectly, however I cannot get it to filter by city now.  Using egrep within the script and piping that through to awk, it shows all cities.  If I run the same command out of the script and into the terminal directly, it works.... Any ideas?

Comment: remove  the '$DATAFILE' from your awk command string; the 'pipe' (match) from grep is sent directly to 'awk' - 'awk' will print everything in the file if you include the file name... [it ignores the data from the 'pipe']...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment yet due to reputation. Another thing you can do is escape the single quotes around your variable names. If you're still having trouble with all cities showing up, I believe it's because you're supplying awk with the filename. It looks like you need to take that out and let the grep's output be used as input for your awk. I don't have access to my linux box to test it but:

your line (having $DATFILE supplied twice):

```
grep -E $city $DATFILE | awk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= $minbed) && ($4 >= $minsqft) && ($5 <= $maxprice) && ($6 <= $maxweeks)' $DATFILE;
```

option 1: remove the second $DATFILE, escape single quotes

```
grep -E $city $DATFILE | awk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= '$minbed') && ($4 >= '$minsqft') && ($5 <= '$maxprice') && ($6 <= '$maxweeks')';
```

option 2: you may be able to get rid of the grep entirely, with escaped single quotes. awk's IGNORECASE should be a substitute for grep's -E.

```
awk -F "[\t]+" 'IGNORECASE = 1;/'$city'/&&($3 >= '$minbed')&&($4 >= '$minsqft')&&($5 <= '$maxprice')&&($6 <= '$maxweeks')';
```

Like I said, can't test it for syntax at the moment; I hope it helps ya.

Happy hacking!