# Piping awk through to sort doesn't sort correctly

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk

Assuming there's a listing.dat file (located: http://pastebin.com/gWkJS2fH)

The following statement will egrep for a city, pipe it through to awk, which will look for any tabs and separate into columns.  I then pipe that data through to sort, which won't sort any columns in ascending order.

I know the reason is due to tabs, but I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.

```
egrep Toronto listing1.dat | gawk -F "[\t]+" '($3 >= 2) && ($4 >= 500) && ($5 <= 900000) && ($6 <= 5)' | sort -nk5
```

This should sort the results in ascending order by price.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Your first command in the pipeline is basic ignored, because you specified an input file to your `gawk` command. That's the first thing I spotted, and I didn't check other parts.

Comment: Yes you are right!  I did spot that myself last night but copied over an older copy of the statement from my terminal.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @4ae1e1 No, the egrep was being ignored so it wasn't filtering by city, but the sorting problem remains.

Comment: Don't ask us to go looking at some other sites to find your data, just edit your question to include a few short lines of sample input and expected output.

Comment: Very helpful @EdMorton.

Comment: I assume that's sarcasm since you didn't actually do what I suggested. That's a shame because you would have received more and better answers from various experts if you had. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `gawk` does not transform the lines out; the address and city are sometimes separated by more than one tab.

What you want, is to set the Output Field Separator to a single Tab. Now sort will find the right column. This is how I would write it:

```
gawk '
        BEGIN{FS="\t+"
        OFS="\t"}
    /Toronto/ && \
    $3 >= 2 && \
    $4 >= 500 && \
    $5 <= 900000 && \
    $6 <= 5 && \
    $1=$1' data | sort -nt$'\t' -k5
```

Edited for some comments:

- Set field separator and output field separator in BEGIN block
- Set the city name as a matcher in the list of conditions
- add `$1=$1` to the conditions. This has the effect that the line is 'recalculated', so the input field separators are replaced with the output field separators.
- Needed some trick to make `sort` listen to `tab` as a separator. `$'\t'` might not be available on all shells, but should be reasonably standard.

Edit 2 to remove the unnecessary `(` and `)` in the conditions.

Comment: This is fantastic, and it's the closest I've come to what I need.  The only problem is that the formatting has been removed.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please consider accepting / upvoting answers.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [AWK doesn't work in Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078381/awk-doesnt-work-in-bash-script), get rid of the unneeded grep first. Your sort may need "-b", meaning to ignore leading blanks; man page here:http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html.

Comment: I need the egrep as I don't know how to filter the city using gawk.  -b didn't make a difference on the sort, with or without egrep.

Comment: I showed you in your previous post:

     `awk -F "[\t]+" 'IGNORECASE = 1;/'$city'/&&($3 >= '$minbed')&&($4 >= '$minsqft')&&($5 <= '$maxprice')&&($6 <= '$maxweeks')';`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$(NF-3)>=2&&$(NF-2)>=500&&$(NF-1)<=900000&&$NF <=5{++j;a[j]=$0;b[j]=$(NF-1)}END{asort(b,c);for(i in c){for(k in b)if(b[k]==c[i]){print a[k];delete b[k]}}}' file
450 West 33rd Street            Toronto         2       890     400000          1
11777 Mississippi Avenue        Toronto         2       890     400000          2
266 King Street West            Toronto         2       840     450000          1
4802 Fifth Avenue               Mississauga     3       1100    450000          5
4500 Wilshire Blvd              Vaughn          3       1420    500000          4
555 Broadway                    Toronto         2       840     500000          4
2213 Mt. Vernon Avenue          Vaughn          2       890     500000          4
1145 17th Street                Toronto         2       790     500000          3
100 Universal City Plaza        Toronto         2       890     580000          1
122 Sherbourne Street           Vaughn          2       690     650000          4
401 Mercer Street               Markham         2       890     700000          4
1416 North LaBrea Avenue        Markham         4       1890    880000          4
One Lincoln Plaza               Toronto         2       980     900000          1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show you what I mean when I say you'd have got better answers if you followed my advice about posting sample input/output, here's one example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t+" }
($2=="Toronto") && ($3>=2) && ($4>=500) && ($5<=900000) && ($6<=5) {
    hits[$5][$0]
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (i in hits) {
        for (j in hits[i]) {
            print j
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
450 West 33rd Street            Toronto         2       890     400000          1
11777 Mississippi Avenue        Toronto         2       890     400000          2
266 King Street West            Toronto         2       840     450000          1
555 Broadway                    Toronto         2       840     500000          4
1145 17th Street                Toronto         2       790     500000          3
100 Universal City Plaza        Toronto         2       890     580000          1
One Lincoln Plaza               Toronto         2       980     900000          1
```

Notice that the formatting is preserved and you don't need any external tools like grep or sort, nor pipes. It also safeguards against the word `Toronto` showing up in the wrong context, e.g. try your accepted answer when the address is `27 Toronto Ave, London` or if it was `27 London Ave, New York` when you want to search for `York`.

The above uses GNU awk 4.* for `sorted_in`.

Answer (score 1):

```
egrep Toronto listing1.dat | gawk -F "\t+" '{if (($3 >= 2) && ($4 >= 500) && ($5 <= 900000) && ($6 <= 5)) {printf $5 "\t"; print}}' | sort -nk1 | cut -f 2-
```

This does a few things:

1) It prepends a copy of the 5th field to the beginning of the row, followed by a single tab.

2) Sorting is now straightforward because you only need to sort on the first column based on single-tab separation. This preserves the variable number of tabs in the rest of the row that make it look nice and aligned (if you need it).

3) Simply use `cut` to keep everything from the 2nd field onwards (i.e. remove the first column that you prepended)